# Is it any good to make play game in zoom out condition?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, zooming, box2d

I'm developing a game with large obstacle and sprites(in cocos2d+box2d for iPhone), then after zooming out my sprites and layer (by increasing cameraZ), I make my game to play by user, which causes some problem in touch detection of dynamic objects.

Can it be said a good approach to work with? If No then what will be the solution to work properly(consider that I have traveled so far with this approach)?

**NOTE:**`[self.camera setEyeX:0 eyeY:0 eyeZ:180];` (i'm using this line for zooming out, putting camera far from my sprites by increasing z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a camera for zooming then cocos2d will no longer correctly convert your touch locations to opengl coordinates, since it doesn't invert the camera transform. I would recommend using scale on the layer that your objects reside on to implement zooming. This gives you precise control over the zoom factor and touches will be correctly transformed when you use methods to convert touches from screen space to node space.

Comment: being mostly unaware on this stuff(scale zooming), can i ask you for little more assistance, can you code the same?